# What is the expected action after an HTML post call to the server?

Tags: html, post, standards

Sorry if this seems like a silly question, but assuming one implements a HTML form with an action triggering a post call to a server, is the server supposed to return the 'next' page or can the post call be twisted to return only a JSON for processing by the same HTML page too?

Is there a standard defining what can or should be done after a HTML post call is performed or is everyone free to do what they want?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> is the server supposed to return the 'next' page

In general, yes, although you can return a `204 No Content` response.

> can the post call be twisted to return only a JSON for processing by the same HTML page too?

It could return JSON, but the page couldn't process it because there is no standard way to process JSON.

If you want to deal with JSON, then you need to make the request with JavaScript instead of a regular form submission.

Comment: Ok, then since I have to go for Javascript, I may as well go for a GET then... Thanks!

Comment: Choosing to use JavaScript to make the request should have no bearing on the choice between GET and POST.

Comment: @JVerstry: No.  GETs should always be idempotent.

Answer (score 1):

The browser will render the response returned by the server.

If you want to handle the response in code, use AJAX instead.